# Stagnant Loss and accuracy with RandomFourierFeatures

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, svm, google-colaboratory

I'm having trouble getting my model to converge. Based on a paper I found that uses SVM as the top of the ResNet, but it's just not working. The RandomFourierTransform I read can be used as a [quasi-substitute](https://keras.io/examples/keras_recipes/quasi_svm/) for SVM in keras

```
# Instantiate ResNet 50 architecture
with strategy.scope():
  t = tf.keras.Input(shape=(256,256,3))
  basemodel = ResNet50(
      include_top=False,
      input_tensor=t,
      weights='imagenet'
  )

# Create ResNET 50 (RGB Channel)
# Pretrained on ImageNet
# Input: RGB Image ==> Output: 2048 element vector
with strategy.scope():
  rgb_model = basemodel.output
  rgb_model = AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(7,7))(rgb_model)
  rgb_model = Flatten()(rgb_model)
  rgb_model = Dense(1000)(rgb_model)
  rgb_model = RandomFourierFeatures(output_dim=2048, scale=5.0, kernel_initializer="gaussian", trainable=True)(rgb_model)
  rgb_model = Dense(len(classes), activation="linear")(rgb_model)

  optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)

  model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=basemodel.input, outputs=rgb_model)
  model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
                loss='hinge',
                metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy(name="acc")])

history = model.fit(train_dataset,
          epochs=epochs,
          steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
          validation_data=val_dataset,
          validation_steps=validation_steps)
```

This is the output I receive

```
Epoch 1/50
  2/234 [..............................] - ETA: 44:41 - loss: 1.4583 - acc: 0.0781  WARNING:tensorflow:Callbacks method `on_train_batch_end` is slow compared to the batch time (batch time: 0.0051s vs `on_train_batch_end` time: 0.0790s). Check your callbacks.

WARNING:tensorflow:Callbacks method `on_train_batch_end` is slow compared to the batch time (batch time: 0.0051s vs `on_train_batch_end` time: 0.0790s). Check your callbacks.

234/234 [==============================] - ETA: 0s - loss: 1.3060 - acc: 0.0452WARNING:tensorflow:Callbacks method `on_test_batch_end` is slow compared to the batch time (batch time: 0.0045s vs `on_test_batch_end` time: 0.0343s). Check your callbacks.

WARNING:tensorflow:Callbacks method `on_test_batch_end` is slow compared to the batch time (batch time: 0.0045s vs `on_test_batch_end` time: 0.0343s). Check your callbacks.

234/234 [==============================] - 75s 320ms/step - loss: 1.3060 - acc: 0.0452 - val_loss: 1.1811 - val_acc: 0.0365
Epoch 2/50
234/234 [==============================] - 21s 91ms/step - loss: 1.1190 - acc: 0.0527 - val_loss: 1.0879 - val_acc: 0.0469
Epoch 3/50
234/234 [==============================] - 21s 92ms/step - loss: 1.0570 - acc: 0.0513 - val_loss: 1.0394 - val_acc: 0.0521
Epoch 4/50
234/234 [==============================] - 21s 91ms/step - loss: 1.0192 - acc: 0.0536 - val_loss: 1.0011 - val_acc: 0.0938
Epoch 5/50
234/234 [==============================] - 21s 91ms/step - loss: 1.0005 - acc: 0.0612 - val_loss: 1.0003 - val_acc: 0.0729
Epoch 6/50
234/234 [==============================] - 21s 92ms/step - loss: 1.0003 - acc: 0.0612 - val_loss: 1.0002 - val_acc: 0.0521
Epoch 7/50
234/234 [==============================] - 22s 92ms/step - loss: 1.0002 - acc: 0.0646 - val_loss: 1.0001 - val_acc: 0.0573
```

Comment: Wait a minute. You use `SGD` and `1` learning rate? There's no way anything more than 2 layers would converge with that!!!

Comment: In the link you attached, it's `Adam` which is easier to converge than `SGD` and lr is `0.001`

Comment: I've changed my optimizer to Adam. I've reflected that in my question. The results are not improved.